# Stack Implementation in Scala

Tags: scala

I would like to get feedback on my code for Stack implementation written in scala. What can be improved to make it more like scala code. What important helper functions am i missing?

```
class StackDS[A] {
  private var list: List[A] = List[A]()


  def push(ele: A) =
    list = ele :: list

  def pop = {
    val pop = list.head
    list = list.tail
    pop
  }

  def size: Int = {
    list.size
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**layout** - The code is clear and easy to read but I find your use of blank lines a bit excessive.

**braces** - Both the `push()` and `size` methods consists of a single line of code so surrounding braces, `{..}`, are optional. You drop them in one and keep them in the other. Inconsistent.

**types** - The `size` method declares its return type but `push()` and `pop` don't. It's usually a good idea to include them in all but the smallest, simplest method definitions.

**mutation** - The mutating collection, `list`, is kept local and `private`, which is good. I might argue that it's better to keep a mutable collection, such as `Buffer` for example, in a `val` variable instead of keeping an immutable collection, `List`, in a `var` variable.

**mutating methods** - For methods with no arguments that mutate an internal state, such as `pop` does, the Scala [Style Guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#parentheses) recommends declaring the method with empty parentheses, `def pop() ...`, as an indicator to the end user.

**safety** - The code will throw an exception if you try to `pop` an empty stack. That may be as you want it. I prefer methods that return `Option[A]` instead of throwing.

**convenience** - If I was trying to use `StackDS` in my code, I'd want to know why stacks have to be created empty. Why can't I create a populated stack? e.g. `new StackDS(8,4,11)` It would require a small modification to the existing code.

What I think your code clearly demonstrates is that a simple `List` does most of what we need from a `Stack`. So even though the Standard Library includes a full featured `Stack` implementation, it's not often used.